# Im trying to combine three various clean url rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

my problem is that I want to get three simple rules working, but my knowledge is too little, to get them working together:

*These are obvious:*

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /register.php [L]
```

**domain.com/login** and **domain.com/register**

*Secondly, since i have only one page used for displaying data, i want its url to be as simple as posible, like:*

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data.php?id=$1 [L]
```

which should be translated into:
**domain.com/1a2s3d**

*As third, I want to be able to change url with activation code:*

```
RewriteRule ^register/activate/([^/]+)$ /register.php?action=activate&code=$1 [L]
```

which finally should be translated into:
**domain.com/register/activate/some-hash**

I know just simply basics. And I cannot mix all of these three ideas into one single working htaccess file. With the second rule the server gives me 500 error, with third rule registration page works, but css file path is translated into domain.com/register/activate/theme/style.css instead of domain.com/theme/style.css

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just with that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register/activate/([^/]+)$ /register.php?action=activate&code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: short anwers are the best, thanks!
but, what does this rule mean - RewriteRule ^ - [L] ?

Comment: With `-f` and `-d`, you just check that there is no real file or directory with the same name. And if that is the case, you do not change anything